# ng-click firing twice for radio buttons

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
<div class="csv-radio-group">
    <input type="radio" id="csv" name="export-type" ng-value="csv" ng-click="$ctrl.setExportType($event, 'csv')">
    <label for="csv">csv</label>
</div>
<div class="qfx-radio-group">
    <input type="radio" id="qfx" name="export-type" ng-value="qfx" ng-click="$ctrl.setExportType($event, 'qfx')">
    <label for="qfx">qfx</label>
</div>
<div class="ofx-radio-group">
    <input type="radio" id="ofx" name="export-type" ng-value="ofx" ng-click="$ctrl.setExportType($event, 'ofx')">
    <label for="ofx">ofx</label>
</div>
```

with the following in my controller:

```
const setExportType = (event, type) => {
    exportTypeSelection = type;
    if(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    console.log(exportTypeSelection);
    console.log(event);
}
```

When I click on the csv button I see:

```
csv
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, 
stopImmediatePropagation: ƒ, isImmediatePropagationStopped: ƒ, 
screenX: 1628, …}
undefined
undefined
```

How come the radio buttons are firing twice and how can I fix this? I'm aware I can use `ng-model` but if I were to use `ng-click` how would this be done? Thanks!

Comment: Try with `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`

Comment: @BillP Doesn't work :/

Comment: Issue is resolved: It was an issue elsewhere in my code

Comment: @JacobL You don't appear to be the OP, unless you are using two accounts on here. What exactly does your comment mean?